# Formatting: how to convert 1 to “01”, 2 to “02”, 3 to "03", and so on

Tags: c++, string, datetime, int, itoa

Following code outputs the values in time format, i.e. if it's 1:50pm and 8 seconds, it would output it as 01:50:08

```
cout << "time remaining: %02d::%02d::%02" << hr << mins << secs;
```

But what I want to do is (a) convert these ints to char/string (b) and then add the same time format to its corresponding char/string value.

I have already achieved (a), I just want to achieve (b).

e.g.

```
    char currenthour[10] = { 0 }, currentmins[10] = { 0 }, currentsecs[10] = { 0 };

    itoa(hr, currenthour, 10);
    itoa(mins, currentmins, 10);
    itoa(secs, currentsecs, 10);
```

Now if I output 'currenthour', 'currentmins' and 'currentsecs', it will output the same example time as, 1:50:8, instead of 01:50:08.

Ideas?

Comment: Your first cout statement works?  it doesn't here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47f11bcdd5421c21

Comment: would it be easier if you convert the values to time_t first?

Comment: I assumed, using %02 was a standard c/c++ practice. Am I wrong? I'm using CryEngine and this statement works there, but instead of cout, CryEngine has a different function. For referece, this works in CryEngine: CryLog("time remaining: %02d::%02d::%02", hr, min, sec);

Comment: I love good old `std::printf`…

Comment: Ah.  No that is not the same.  It is like `printf`.  `printf` and `cout` are completely different beast.

Comment: NathanOliver: I know, that's why I am posting a (perhaps) useless comment and not an answer.

Comment: @styko My comment was direct to the OP's comment before your.  We posted at just about the exact same time so your comment was there.

Comment: Since you are using C++ it would be much better using `std::string` and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) or [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind the overhead you can use a `std::stringstream`

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string to_format(const int number) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << number;
    return ss.str();
}
```

Comment: I would change your opening sentence to: ""Use a 'std::stringstream'". Performance should only be a concern once the software works correctly but doesn't meet its timing constraints.

Comment: @RichN Feel free to edit my post. Although to me the OP suggested that a rather low level implementation is used/wanted, which is why I added the performance hint. Nevertheless I completely agree to your argument.

Answer (score 4):

As from your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35608291/formatting-how-to-convert-1-to-01-2-to-02-3-to-03-and-so-on#comment58901004_35608291):

> *"I assumed, using %02 was a standard c/c++ practice. Am I wrong?"*

Yes, you are wrong. Also c/c++ isn't a thing, these are different languages.

C++ `std::cout` doesn't support `printf()` like formatting strings. What you need is [`setw()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`setfill()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill):

```
cout << "time remaining: " << setfill('0')
     << setw(2) <<  hr << ':' << setw(2) << mins << ':' << setw(2) << secs;
```

---

If you want a `std::string` as result, you can use a `std::ostringstream` in the same manner:

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << setfill('0')
     << setw(2) <<  hr << ':' << setw(2) << mins << ':' << setw(2) << secs;
cout << "time remaining: " << oss.str();
```

---

Also there's a boost library [`boost::format`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) available, that resembles the format string/place holder syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) ([godbolt](https://www.godbolt.org/z/qTTofaz9f)):

```
std::string s = std::format("time remaining: {:02}::{:02}::{:02}",
                            hr, mins, secs);
```

On older systems you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.